# Pandas Melt duplication issue

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe that with dates as columns, I've been trying to do a melt() in order to get the multiple column with dates into one column and the values in another:

Here is the first dataframe before the melt()

```
Full Acct           Actt_Num     Type 1   Desc. 1/31/2019   2/28/2019   3/31/2023   4/30/2023   5/31/2023
    0     500 - Rev           500                                        8,885       65,777
    1     132 - Prepaid Exp   132                           
    2     NaN                 NaN                           
    3     NaN                 NaN                           
    4     133 - Prepaid Exp   133                35,164.0   
    5     NaN                 NaN          adj     
    6     NaN                 NaN          adj  
    7     134 - Prepaid Exp2  134          adj   225,456.0 
    8     NaN                 NaN          adj                                   





  import pandas as pd
    
    df =  pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\folder/Dataset.xlsx',
                                    sheet_name='Tbl', usecols='A:BQ', header=1, dtype=object,engine = 'openpyxl')
            
 
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Full Acct', 'Acct_Num','Type 1','Desc.' ], var_name='Date',value_name='value')
```

**This is he output I get:**

```
     Full Acct         Actt_Num  Type 1      Desc.  Date        Value
0     500 - Rev           500                       1/31/2019               
1     132 - Prepaid Exp   132                       1/31/2019   
2     NaN                 NaN                       1/31/2019   
3     NaN                 NaN                       1/31/2019   
4     133 - Prepaid Exp   133                       1/31/2019   35,164.0 
5     NaN                 NaN                 adj   1/31/2019    
6     NaN                 NaN                 adj   1/31/2019
7     134 - Prepaid Exp2  134                 adj   1/31/2019   225,456.0 
8     NaN                 NaN                 adj   1/31/2019
9     500 - Rev           500                       2/28/2019               
10    132 - Prepaid Exp   132                       2/28/2019   
11    NaN                 NaN                       2/28/2019   
12    NaN                 NaN                       2/28/2019   
13    133 - Prepaid Exp   133                       2/28/2019   
14    NaN                 NaN                 adj   2/28/2019    
15    NaN                 NaN                 adj   2/28/2019
16    134 - Prepaid Exp2  134                 adj   2/28/2019    
17    NaN                 NaN                 adj   2/28/2019
```

It seems that I am getting duplicates in the columns that were not pivoted, why is this happening?  ideally the output will not have duplicate info in the 'Full Acct', 'Acct_Num','Type 1','Desc. if they do not have a value for the month

Comment: can you just drop the blank rows afterwards? your dataframe does include these cells - pandas is faithfully executing melt. it's totally fine for you to filter the data after melt.

Comment: i see, actually i would need to drop the ones with data but no dollar value for the other months, any advice on how to do that ? e.g ( Feb 2019 should just have a blank row for every column

Comment: If you can, kindly share the excel file as a download

Comment: @sammywemmy  I think all i need now is how to fix my output, how do i delete data  in the data frame  for the forward months that do not have value?